# Catching a "canceled" event from the server

Tags: java, javascript, spring-roo

I have a pretty dumb page that uses Java as the server.  The page currently allows the user to upload an excel file and the server parses through it.

Now the trick is, when there are errors in the file (invalid data types, etc), I'm recreating an excel file with the error rows highlighted and returning that to the browser.

If there are errors that are bigger than just a row (say if they upload a non-excel file), I redirect them to a "your bad" page.

The problem is, I would like to give the user a simple loading spinner while the file is uploaded and processed.  I've tried several jQuery plugins but javascript doesn't catch anything when a file is returned.  The network tab of chrome's debugger says that the POST was "canceled".  I assume this is because my server isn't returning a redirect, it's returning a document:

```
if (hasErrors) {
    log.debug("Errors were found, returning workbook");
    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=errorBook.xlsx");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        errorBook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unable to write to the output stream", e);
    }
}
log.debug("No errors found in workbook upload");
return "redirect:/uploadfiles/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(uf.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
```

I'm using SpringRoo for my server side, which is using tiles and the like.  Notice the "return null" when I'm returning a file.  I'm unable to return anything because it complains that the output stream has already been written to.

Has anyone else had an issue like this?  Is this a strange situation to be in?  Is there a way for javascript to catch the "server has canceled the form post"?

EDIT:  Here's the jQuery that I'm using now.  Things have changed since I originally posted, but the issue persists.  I'm using the fileupload plugin now, and found that when I force the iFrame, the file downloads but none of the done/fail/always callbacks are called.

```
$("#uploadFile").fileupload({
    forceIframeTransport : true
})
    .bind("fileuploadsubmit", function(e, data) {
                    console.log("submitting");
    })
    .bind("fileuploaddone", function(e, data) {
        console.log("success!");
    })
    .bind("fileuploadfail", function(e, data) {
        console.log("Fail");
    })
    .bind("fileuploadalways", function(e, data) {
                    console.log("always");
    });
```

If I remove the force iframe, the callbacks are fired, but the document is not downloaded.  In fact, in this case the data contains a string of the file object (which is just a smattering of bytes).

Comment: Can you post your jQuery?  I'd also be interested to see if you put a breakpoint in on your post return what you are getting back.  You could do this in Chrome, Firefox using Firebug, or IE if you have the Developer Tools installed.

Comment: So no breakpoint is being hit when the request is canceled.  I'll post my findings later, I was able to figure out the issue but I don't have the code in front of me right now.
It basically came down to using a cookie, and sniffing the cookie every second.  The server sends down the cookie when it sends down the file.